# combine if in Where (entityFramework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any way to combine this line into one?

```
if(List1.count>0 && List2.count>0 && List3.count>0)
{
    ctx.table.where(o=>List1.contains(o.item1) && List2.contains(o.item2)  &&  List3.contains(o.item3))
}

else if(List1.count>0 && List2.count>0 && List3.count==0)
{
    ctx.table.where(o=>List1.contains(o.item1) && List2.contains(o.item2)) 
}

else if(List1.count>0 && List2.count==0 && List3.count>0)
{
    ctx.table.where(o=>List1.contains(o.item1) && List3.contains(o.item3)) 
}
...
```

Something like this

```
 ctx.table.where(o=>if(List1.count>0) List1.contains(o.item1) && if(List2.count>0) List2.contains(o.item2) && if(List3.count>0) List3.contains(o.item3))
```

Comment: What's the type of List1, List2 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ allows you to have multiple `Where` conditions. So the easiest way would be to use separate the `Where` conditions for each `List`.

```
IEnumerable<int> collection = ctx.table;
if(list1.Count > 0)
{
    collection = collection.Where(o => list1.Contains(o.item1));
}
if(list2.Count > 0)
{
    collection = collection.Where(o => list2.Contains(o.item2));
}
if(list3.Count > 0)
{
    collection = collection.Where(o => list3.Contains(o.item3));
}
```

If you really want to have just 1 line, you can combine these conditions into 1 using `listX.Count > 0 ? listX.Contains(o.itemX) : true`
The result would be:

```
IEnumerable<int> collection = ctx.table.Where(o => 
    list1.Count > 0 ? list1.Contains(o.item1) : true && 
    list2.Count > 0 ? list2.Contains(o.item2) : true &&
    list3.Count > 0 ? list3.Contains(o.item3) : true);
```

Comment: do you think this is going to work on `IEnumerable`? ;)

Comment: @Leo the **non-generic** type? No, it will not, because the LINQ extension methods are only implemented on the generic `IEnumerable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
ctx.table.where(o=> List1.count>0 ? List1.contains(o.item1) : true && List2.count>0 ? List2.contains(o.item2) : true && List3.count>0 ? List3.contains(o.item3) : true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var found = ctx.table.Where(o => (!List1.Any() || List1.Contains(o.item1))
                                 && (!List2.Any() || List2.Contains(o.item2))
                                 && (!List3.Any() || List3.Contains(o.item3)));
```

Note that `ListX.Any()` is inherently short-circuiting and hence performs better than `ListX.Count > 0`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem when there is string List and int List together

```
Where(o=>(Stringlist1.Count > 0) ? Stringlist1.Contains(o.string1) : true && 
(Intlist1.Count > 0 ?) Intlist1.Contains(o.Int1) : true)
```

But if separate them in two where it works fine

```
Where(o=>(Stringlist1.Count > 0) ? Stringlist1.Contains(o.string1) : true ).Where(o=> 
(Intlist1.Count > 0 ?) Intlist1.Contains(o.Int1) : true)
```

Do you have any idea?

///////////////////////////////////////

I found the solution ,all part must be in parentheses

```
Where(o=>((Stringlist1.Count > 0) ? Stringlist1.Contains(o.string1) : true ) && 
  ((Intlist1.Count > 0 ?) Intlist1.Contains(o.Int1) : true))
```